# Implementing a liftIO-Style lift for Monad-Transformers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am currently learning to use Monad-Transformers in Haskell. I have composed a simple
Monad-Transformer using [`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html) and [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html):

```hs
type DatabaseT m = StateT DatabaseState (ExceptT DatabaseError m)
```

There are already some functions working with `DatabaseT` like:

```hs
connectDB :: MonadIO m => DBMode -> DatabaseT m ()
isConnected :: Monad m => DatabaseT m Bool
```

To make lifting of such functions easier I want to define a type-class
similar to [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO):

```hs
class Monad m => MonadDB m where
  liftDB :: Monad m' => DatabaseT m' a -> m a
```

Now the problematic part is making `DatabaseT m` an instance if `MonadDB`.
Looking at the [implementation of `MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#MonadIO) this function should be the identity function:

```hs
instance Monad m => MonadDB (DatabaseT m) where
  liftDB = id
```

However this code does not compile:

```
Couldn't match type ‘m'’ with ‘m’
  ‘m'’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      liftDB :: forall (m' :: * -> *) a.
                Monad m' =>
                DatabaseT m' a -> DatabaseT m a
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
  Expected type: DatabaseT m' a -> DatabaseT m a
    Actual type: DatabaseT m a -> DatabaseT m a
In the expression: id
  In an equation for ‘liftDB’: liftDB = id
  In the instance declaration for ‘MonadDB (DatabaseT m)’
Relevant bindings include
    liftDB :: DatabaseT m' a -> DatabaseT m a
```

It seems having a Monad-Transformer type-class for a Monad `MyMonad`, with `liftMyMonad` like
functions, does not work when `MyMonad` is a Monad-Transformer itself.

Is this a valid approach to make lifting of `DatabaseT m` actions more generic or
is it fundamentally flawed?

If so, how can I lift `DatabaseT m` actions from anywhere on top of a `DatabaseT`
stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end state you ask for probably isn't the end state you want.  Namely this is not great for most needs:

```
class Monad m => MonadDB m where
  liftDB :: Monad m' => DatabaseT m' a -> m a
```

The typical solution is to not write such an instance at all and instead write:

```
class Monad m => MonadDB m where
  connectDB :: DBMode -> m ()
  isConnected :: m Bool
```

This allows you to:

- Use the functions in monadic contexts where DatabaseT is a component
- Use solutions like MonadMock for testing
- Not break abstraction - avoid using `lift` in the consumer code at all.

Comment: Indeed, the end state they ask for is basically uninhabitable in any sane way. Any putative instance has to be able to embed *all* other monads. Yikes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I have to make sure all my `DatabaseT` actions are part of the `MonadDB` class.  If I understand correctly there is no way to generalize functions that can be run on `MonadDB` instances without making the state maintainable?

Comment: Not the only way. I could imagine type trickery to tye that m' with m. Another db solution just exposes the connection (see [MonadSelda](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/selda-0.5.1.0/docs/Database-Selda.html#t:MonadSelda))